# Drilling down in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, drilldown

I do hope I can explain this well enough to make sense.  I have a Google map that I place a Grid upon.  The Grid is actually polylines of longitude and latitude lines that layout 1/4 minute grids.  This is fired by the Idle event.

When I user clicks the map, the createGridBox(event.latLng) function is called and in doing so, creates a gridOverBox within the GridBox that outlines the particular Grid of interest.  It also creates a sub-Grid within that box and divides it into 8ths.

In my present code, another GridBox is also created since I arbitrarily call createMicroGrid to create a smGridOverBox around the click event point.  That is just for testing.

What I want to happen is :

1. When a click event occurs, if it is in a GridBox that does not have the subgrids drawn, Draw them.
2. If a subgrid already exists, create a smGridOverBox at that point by calling  createMicroGrid(point).

I hope this is not too confusing.

The code is there to create all the grids.  What is missing is the script to test if the subGrid already has the latlon lines inside that grid box.  I added (commented out) some pseudo code to help explain what I am trying to do.

thanks
Springer

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry&amp;sensor=false"></script>
            <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://melterium.net/label.js"></script>-->
    <title>Find your Qtr minute locator</title>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;margin:0">
<!-- Declare the div, make it take up the full document body -->
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 95%;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;

    var qtrArray = [];
    var Startlatlng;
    var llOffset = 0.0666666666666667;
    var smallGridOffset = llOffset/8;
    var drawGridBox = false;
    var drawSmGridBox = false;

    var gridline;
    var polylinesquare;
    var latPolylines = [];
    var smLatPolylines = [];
    var latLabels = [];
    var latMapLabel;

    var lngPolylines = [];
    var smLngPolylines = [];
    var lngLabels = [];
    var lngMapLabel;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.00, -84.00),
            zoom: 10,
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scaleControl: true
        });

        /*
         var oLat = 90.00;
         var oLon = 0.00;

         var gridlocator = [new google.maps.LatLng(oLat, oLon)];
         */
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
//            if gridOverBox does not exist then        <<= pseudo code
//            createGridBox(event.latLng)
//            else
//            createMicroGrid(event.latLng);
            createGridBox(event.latLng);
            createMicroGrid(event.latLng);
        });
        DrawGridOn();
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
            createGridLines(map.getBounds());
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function DrawGridOn() {
        drawGridBox = true;
    }

    function DrawGridOff() {
        drawGridBox = false;
    }


    function ClearLastGrid() {
        polyline.setMap(null);
    }

//    function drawPolyLine(from, to, orient)

    function createGridLines(bounds) {
        for (var i = 0; i < latPolylines.length; i++) {
            latPolylines[i].setMap(null);
        }

        latPolylines = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < lngPolylines.length; i++) {
            lngPolylines[i].setMap(null);
        }
        lngPolylines = [];

        if (map.getZoom() < 10) return;
        var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var east  = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
        var west  = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();

        // define the size of the grid
        var topLat = Math.ceil(north / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var rightLong = Math.ceil(east / llOffset) * llOffset;

        var bottomLat = Math.floor(south / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var leftLong = Math.floor(west / llOffset) * llOffset;

        for (var latitude = bottomLat; latitude <= topLat; latitude += llOffset) latPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, leftLong), new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, rightLong)],
            map: map,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 1
        }));
        for (var longitude = leftLong; longitude <= rightLong; longitude += llOffset) lngPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(topLat, longitude), new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLat, longitude)],
            map: map,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 1
        }));
    }

    function createGridBox(point) {
        // Square limits
//        var smPoint = point;
        var bottomLeftLat = Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var bottomLeftLong = Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset;

        var i;

        var gridLineSquare = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong), //lwr left
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong + llOffset), //lwr right
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong + llOffset), //upr right
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong), //upr left
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong)]; //lwr left

        // external.getData(event.latLng);
        if (drawGridBox == true) {

            gridOverBox = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: gridLineSquare,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#CC0099',
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });


            for (var latitude = bottomLeftLat + smallGridOffset; latitude <= (bottomLeftLat + llOffset); latitude += smallGridOffset) smLatPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                    new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, bottomLeftLong), new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, bottomLeftLong + llOffset)],
                map: map,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#0000FF',
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 1
            }));

            for (var longitude = bottomLeftLong + smallGridOffset; longitude <= bottomLeftLong + llOffset; longitude += smallGridOffset) smLngPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                    new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, longitude), new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, longitude)],
                map: map,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#0000FF',
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 1
            }));


            gridOverBox.setMap(map);

            qtrArray.push(gridOverBox);

            drawSmGridBox = true;

        }

    }

    function createMicroGrid(point){
        // Square limits
        var bottomLeftLat = Math.floor(point.lat() / smallGridOffset) * smallGridOffset;
        var bottomLeftLong = Math.floor(point.lng() / smallGridOffset) * smallGridOffset;

        var i;

        var smGridLineSquare = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong), //lwr left
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong + smallGridOffset), //lwr right
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + smallGridOffset, bottomLeftLong + smallGridOffset), //upr right
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + smallGridOffset, bottomLeftLong), //upr left
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong)]; //lwr left

        // external.getData(event.latLng);
        if (drawSmGridBox == true) smGridOverBox = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: smGridLineSquare,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
        smGridOverBox.setMap(map);
        map.setZoom(14);
    }


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What issues are you having implementing the code required to meet your requirements?

Comment: @geocodezip
I need the equivalent of
//            if gridOverBox does not exist then        <<= pseudo code
//            createGridBox(event.latLng)
//            else
//            createMicroGrid(event.latLng);
What I am trying to determine is if the point where the user clicks, does an smGridLineSquare already exists?  If so, run createMicroGrid(event.latLng) for that point.  
I can't use containsLocation since the inner box is comprised of lat/lon polylines, rather than polygons.  (unless there is a way to convert the lat/lon grids to polygons).

Comment: How did you plan on detecting if gridOverBox does not exist

Comment: that is, in essence, my question.  If I knew that, I'd have it solved.

Comment: @geocodezip,
Since there will only be one gridOverBox that delineates the Grid of interest, I will be able to test if the point falls within that box.  If so, create the smGridOverBox box.  If not, delete the existing gridOverBox  and create a new one.
By jove old  boy, I think you walked me into it with your Socratic questioning! (whether intentional or not).

Answer (score 0):

first, I had to declare

```
var gridOverBox = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#CC0099',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 2
});
```

as Script global so it is visible to the `addListener` method.  Then I added

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
if (!google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, gridOverBox)) 
    createGridBox(event.latLng)
    else
    createMicroGrid(event.latLng);
});
```

I know that the script is badly in need of refactoring, but I am new to JS and this does work.